# How to create a group of methods/properties within a class?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, web-services, entity-framework

I am using entity framework with a web service and I have entity partial class objects that were generated automatically by the web service.

I would like to extend these classes, but I would like to group them in the generated class in a way similar to the way a namespace would (except inside a class).

Here is my generated class:

```
public partial class Employee : Entity
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to add some new properties, functions, etc similar to:

```
public partial class Employee : Entity
{
   public string FullName {
      get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
   }
}
```

However, I would like to group any additional properties together so I have a little more visible separation from the generated methods. I would like to be able to call something like:

```
myEmployee.CustomMethods.FullName
```

I could create another class within the partial class called CustomMethods and pass a reference to the base class so I can access the generated properties. Or maybe just name them a particular way. But, I am not sure what is the best solution. I am looking for community ideas that are clean and fall under good practice. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, why do you want to group those custom properties? sometimes you can use Attributes to mark them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is another solution using explicit interfaces:

```
public interface ICustomMethods {
    string FullName {get;}
}

public partial class Employee: Entity, ICustomMethods {
    public ICustomMethods CustomMethods {
       get {return (ICustomMethods)this;}
    }
    //explicitly implemented
    string ICustomMethods.FullName {
       get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string fullName;
fullName = employee.FullName; //Compiler error    
fullName = employee.CustomMethods.FullName; //OK
```

Comment: +1 using explicit interfaces makes code more readable with good extensibility.

Comment: is it possible to force that interface to be explicit?

Comment: The interface is explicitly implemented when you have default accessibility and prepend the interface name to the property/method name. The "explicitness" is in the implementation, not in the interface itself.

Comment: Please be aware that such classes will not bind in MVC3

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomMethods
{
    Employee _employee;
    public CustomMethods(Employee employee)
    {
        _employee = employee;
    }

    public string FullName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                _employee.FirstName, _employee.LastName); 
        }
    }
}

public partial class Employee : Entity
{
    CustomMethods _customMethods;
    public CustomMethods CustomMethods
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_customMethods == null)
                _customMethods = new CustomMethods(this);
            return _customMethods;
        }
    }
}
```

typically I would put Properties like `FullName` right on the Partial class but I can see why you might want separation.

Comment: I think that's what you were saying toward the end of your question. I guess this answer isn't terrible and gets the separation you're looking for.